# Include javascript files content in ob_start buffer

Tags: javascript, php, output, buffer, ob-start

I am currently working on the translation of a website. 
To perform this translation easily, I created a `.csv file` containing the matches between the two languages (japanese->english).
Then, this file is parsed with PHP, and `ob_start()` is called on the page in order to replace wanted strings.

Here is the script :

```
    function lang_modify($buffer){

               require('get_messages.php');
               for($i=0; $i<count($messages); $i++){
                   $buffer = str_replace($messages[$i][0], $messages[$i][1], $buffer);
               }

                return $buffer;

        }

   $buffer = ob_start('lang_modify');
```

This script works perfectly on php/html files. However, ob_start does not read javascript files so I was wondering if someone knows a way to include javascript files into the output buffer so that the `ob_start()` function will replace the words found in javascript as well.

Someone adviced me to do search something with the `AddFile` statement `(.htaccess)`, but I don't know at all how could I use this to do what I want.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Comment: Does it work when you add the script to the file instead of having it in a separate file?

Comment: It would work if the Javascript code was written directly into each pages, but I am not allowed to do that in this kind of project.

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing here, is a **Separation of Concerns** issue.

Your translation is generated from *PHP*.

And yet, your javascript displays and (sometimes) generates those messages.

**How do i fix this?**

1) Make sure your translations comes from one single source, ideally from **PHP**

2) Use an i18n js library to process your translations. I suggest: https://airbnb.github.io/polyglot.js/

3) If you are using Polyglot, make sure that your PHP translations are being generated into a js file, which is then loaded based on localisation.

Polygot will translate your default messages into internationalized ones.

**In short:**

- Enable Modularity - Administer(CRUD) all your translations in PHP. Storing them in a database
  would be ideal
- Decouple JS from translation - Polygot will only provide the translated messages to your views(HTML).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mysteryos.
However, there is some aspects that I forget to explain.

The website is quite a huge project and has been created by combinating Wordpress and FuelPHP. It is also used by other members of the company and according to the task I was given I won't be allowed to modify the structure of the website, or install some libraries on the server (In fact I don't even have access to the server).

So what I want here is not to apply an isolated way of translation for JS files, but trying to include the js file in the output buffer created with the process I explained.

Comment: Wordpress has an i18n module(with handling of js files), have you tried looking into that? I am afraid, with your constraints, there is little choice. The solution proposed above, will provide your project with the lowest technical and maintainability debt, which should be your aim throughout this task, other than completing it.